# Difference between to many people and for many people

Tags: prepositions

I know that there is a duplicated post here: 
https://www.google.com/search?q=to+many+people+or+for+many+people&oq=to+many+people+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.7519j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

However, it does not help me a lot. Could anyone tell me which is correct in the following sentences:

1.We understand that **to** many people, animal welfare is a secondary priority in their busy lives.

2.We understand that **for** many people, animal welfare is a secondary priority in their busy lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is correct. The reasoning is that *for* usually describes conditions that hold in general for certain groups, while *to* goes to show that a condition doesn't hold in general for members of a group, just on special occasions. This is because *to* is usually associated with the act of giving something to someone.

For example, consider these two sentences:
1) *Free schooling is available to these children.*
2) *Free schooling is available for these children.*
Here the first sentence illustrates that these children might be priveleged to have schooling and other kids might not have the same access. In the second sentence however the sentiment is that all children have free schooling and therefore also this particular group of children. So in this example *for* would be correct since all people that fall into the category of *many people* find animal welfare a secondary priority.

Comment: Very clear and nice explanation, I understand that, thanks